# What is the process for filing individual income tax for income obtained without a W-2 or 1099?

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs, form-1040

#### Scenario

We have a legal adult called Brittany who has obtained income of $4096.00 from a babysitting job last year.

The mother of the children she has been watching has *not* withheld income taxes, social security, or Medicare for Brittany.

A W-4 or other IRS documentation have not been utilized prior to employment. And after January 31st (the deadline for issuing) a W-2/1099 have not been given to Brittany.

The only records are of the mother’s tracking on amounts she’s paid Brittany.

#### Questions

1. How can Brittany correctly file her income with the IRS given the situation?
2. How can the mother fix the documentation and filing mistakes she made the previous year?

#### Findings

It seems that Brittany can attach [Schedule 1](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1040s1.pdf) to her 1040 and put her income on line 8 with the description of “Babysitting” and file her 1040 as normal? Is there any other steps for completion or is this the incorrect process?

As far as the employer (the mother) goes, it looks like it would be more involved. From a bit of research, it looks like she would have to attach [Schedule H](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1040sh.pdf) to her own personal tax filings and pay and account for things she missed previously. But I’m unsure if she has to issue a W-2 late in addition or if there’s any other requirements?

Comment: Is the employer willing or unwilling to issue a W-2 to Brittany?

Comment: @user102008 Yes. Both Brittany and the employer (mother) are willing to bring the scenario to full compliance with the IRS.

Comment: It seems to me (though I'm not an expert) that Brittany is self-employed, no?  That is, she babysits, or could babysit, for a number of different people.  (Even if she actually babysat only for this one person.)  So shouldn't she file Schedule C, and any other forms that let her deduct self-employment expenses?  Then if the remaining income is large enough, she files Schedule SE for Social Security tax.

Comment: @jamesqf I thought at first that might be the case. Either self-employed individual or independent contractor. But because the employer (the mother) sets the wage, the working hours, and tasks it would seem Brittany would be an employee? And for simplicity, let’s just assume she doesn’t itemize deductions and instead opts for the standard ($12,200)

Comment: I would not think Brittany would be an employee, unless there is some sort of exclusive agreement (as with an au pair or nanny).  It'd be more like for instance hiring a band for an event, or to play at your nightclub.  The setting of hours and general nature of the tasks are inherent in the work: e.g. "play music from 8 to midnight" or "stay with kids from 8 to midnight", but not really specifying how the music is played, or what she does with the kids.  WRT deductions, I meant expenses related to babysitting business that could be deducted before SS is calculated.